# Move up and down table relationships in one query

Tags: mysql, join

**What I want to do**

I have three tables. the `words` table, the `relationships` table which takes two ids from the words table using `a_key` and `b_key`, and `contexts` table, which takes two ids from the relationships table using `x_key` and `y_key`. I want to take a word from the word table, find every instance of it in the relationships table, and every instance of those relationships in the contexts table, and work my way down the relationships to get all words that are connected by proxy.

**What's I'm trying**

The data

```
words
id      word
3       car
5       road
9       wheel

relationships
id      a_key   b_key
1       3       5
2       5       9

contexts
id      x_key   y_key
1       1       2
```

Goal

When I get the word car, to know that it has been used in the same sentence as wheel. So I give it ID of 3, and 3 has a relation to ID 5, which has a context to a relationship between ID 5 and ID 9, I should be able to return the word for ID 9.

The query

```
        select * from `words` 
        left join `relationships` 
            on relationships.a_key in (3,5,9)
            left join `contexts`
                on relationships.id = contexts.y_key
```

This is as far as I've been able to get.

**What I'm missing**

What I don't understand how to do, is use results from a query to build another query without starting a new query. I've looking into using aliases `AS a`, and layered selects `SELECT *, (SELECT *, (SELECT *` but I haven't found anything that makes sense as to how it's applied in this case.

Comment: Can you show some rows from each table.

Comment: Can you also show the result you expect to get?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Updated the question with. "When I get the word car, to know that it has been used in the same sentence as wheel. So I give it ID of 1, and 1 has a relation to ID 2, which has a context to a relationship between ID 2 and ID 3, I should be able to return the word for ID 3."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is SQL that will give the word relationships for a given `contexts` ID, in this case `contexts` ID 1.

This selects twice from the `contexts` table using a `UNION`.  The first one joining on the `x_key` too `relationships` and then to `words` on both the `a_key` and the `b_key`.  The second joining on the `y_key` to `relationships` and then to `words` on both the `a_key` and the `b_key`

```
SELECT
  w_1.word,
  w_2.word
FROM
    contexts c
    LEFT JOIN relationships r_1 ON r_1.id = c.x_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_1 ON w_1.id = r_1.a_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_2 ON w_2.id = r_1.b_key
WHERE
    c.id = 1

UNION

SELECT
  w_1.word,
  w_2.word
FROM
    contexts c
    LEFT JOIN relationships r_1 ON r_1.id = c.y_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_1 ON w_1.id = r_1.a_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_2 ON w_2.id = r_1.b_key
WHERE
    c.id = 1
    ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20d8f/18) results

```
word    word
car     road
road    wheel
```

Update, to select on the word you can do the following.

```
SELECT
  w_1.word,
  w_2.word
FROM
    contexts c
    LEFT JOIN relationships r_1 ON r_1.id = c.x_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_1 ON w_1.id = r_1.a_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_2 ON w_2.id = r_1.b_key
WHERE
    w_1.word = 'car'

UNION

SELECT
  w_1.word,
  w_2.word
FROM
    contexts c
    LEFT JOIN relationships r_1 ON r_1.id = c.y_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_1 ON w_1.id = r_1.a_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_2 ON w_2.id = r_1.b_key
WHERE
    w_2.word = 'car'
    ;
```

[SQL Fiddle results for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20d8f/23)

```
word    word
car     road
```

Comment: You're using the context id as input. I need to use word id as input.

Comment: Your question said one thing, but your comments said something else.  Maybe clarify your question.   You can change c.id = 1 to w_1.word = 'car'

Comment: I'm sorry. It's difficult to clearly communicate these ideas because I'm not fluent in working with `JOIN`S and `UNION`S. I have made an edit to your answer reflecting what I'm looking for. I'll try to clarify my question. By the way, you format your queries very well, and it makes it easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was only trying to save you time. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, mate:

```
SELECT
    w_1.*,
    w_2.*
FROM
    words w_1
    LEFT JOIN relationships r_1 ON r_1.a_key = w_1.id
    LEFT JOIN contexts c ON c.x_key = r_1.id
    LEFT JOIN relationships r_2 ON r_2.id = c.y_key
    LEFT JOIN words w_2 ON w_2.id = r_2.b_key
WHERE
    w_1.word = 'car';
```

**E:** The result is based on my understanding that you expect another word coming from your initial input, which is *car*, and the 2nd one is *wheel*.

**UPDATE**

Try this one, mate:

```
SELECT
    w2.*
FROM
    words w1
    INNER JOIN relationships r1 ON r1.a_key = w1.id
    INNER JOIN relationships r2 ON r2.a_key = r1.b_key
    INNER JOIN contexts c1 ON c1.x_key = r1.id OR c1.x_key = r2.id
    INNER JOIN relationships r3 ON r3.id = c1.y_key
    INNER JOIN words w2 ON w2.id = r3.b_key
WHERE
    w1.word = 'car';
```

**E:** This one returns records in the words table which has a relationships.id based on the context record of either the word or the one it has relationship. The relationship is based from the root table, which is words(w_1). Hope this can help, cheers.

Comment: This has shed some light on on what I want and how to do it, unfortunately, your query is only returning what I pass it. So if I pass it the word car, it returns the word car. I'll play with it, and see if I can find a solution building off of this. Please see if you can fix/explain how to use your query. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello @Goose, thanks for the response. I changed something in the query, maybe can try it now. Cheers

Comment: Output is still the same word as the output.

Comment: I meant to type, "Output is still the same word as the input"

Comment: @Goose, you can user either INNER or LEFT JOIN for the update based on your preference. Hope it can help you

Comment: @Avidos your latest SQL has an error, you select from w3 which doesn't exist as an alias in your FROM

Comment: @Avidos No problem.  Although from what he asks in his comments I don't think that is quite what he is after either, so I've posted my own answer, but given you an upvote :-)